# UINT_MAX the same as ULONG_MAX in C

Tags: c, max, long-integer, unsigned, kr-c

While solving exercises from the K&R C book, I stumbled upon the exercise 2.1.

At first I got as `UINT_MAX` as `-1`, but then I used the `%u` placeholder, but now its giving me the same number as `ULONG_MAX`.

In the book in Appendix B, they say that `UINT_MAX` should be `65535` and `ULONG_MAX` should be `4294967295`, but when running the exercise, its giving me for both `UINT_MAX` and `ULONG_MAX` as `4294967295`.

Why is that?

Comment: On Mac OS X 64-bit apps, `ULONG_MAX` = `ULONGLONG_MAX`, and `ULONG_MAX` ≠ `UINT_MAX`.  Specifically `UINT_MAX=4294967295`,  `ULONG_MAX=18446744073709551615`, and `ULONG_LONG_MAX=18446744073709551615`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the right way to print an `unsigned long` is not `%u` but `%lu`. Second, the standard says *the minimum* value of `UINT_MAX` is 65535. It can be (and usually is) larger.

> 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types
>
> Their implementation-deﬁned values shall be **equal or greater in
>   magnitude** (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.

Comment: Ohh, I see
I didnt see the minimum magnitude
Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

On 32-bit platforms, `int` and `long` are usually the same, and so their max are also the same. The same for their unsigned counterparts of course.

Answer (score 0):

The appendix is wrong.  The only guarantee is that sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int) >= sizeof(char)  note the possibility of equality.