# Why does the maximum value of datatypes showing an absurdly high value?

Tags: c

I was doing problem 2.1 of K&R C which basically wants us to mess around and understand the header library

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<float.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%lu", ULONG_MAX);
}
```

When I run this program, I get the output

```
4294967295
```

which is equal to 2<sup>32</sup> -1. I was expecting this value (since K&R has the same value in it's appendix).

Now I changed `%lu` to `%llu`.

With my little knowledge of the C language, I am assuming that `%llu` is a bigger 'placeholder' for the value of `ULONG_MAX`.

I expected to get the same output, but instead I got a vague output

```
38654705663
```

Isn't `ULONG_MAX` supposed to be a constant? Why is it changing?
Also, in quest for an answer, I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749930/uint-max-the-same-as-ulong-max-in-c).

I understand the argument that the standard mentions the term 'minimum' but when I tested this with `CHAR_MAX` (i.e. tried to print `CHAR_MAX` with a `%llu` specifier), I got

```
38654705663
```

This is contradictory to everything I have ever read about `char` in C.

Really hope that someone clears the confusion regarding this.

Comment: @hvd Ok, I see how the offhandishness is ambiguous. I removed my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types of additional `printf()` parameters *must* match used placeholders. Otherwise the behaviour is undefined.

`%llu` stands for `unsigned long long`, thus your parameter also has to be `unsigned long long`:

```
printf("%llu", (unsigned long long)ULONG_MAX);
```

Comment: Isn't it a constant, so why does it display some other value?
Should it not overflow?

Comment: @KaranSingh There is a thing called *"undefined behaviour"*. It means that your program is not guaranteed to function properly anymore, and anything can happen with it. This term is used a lot in the standard in phrases like *"If you <do something silly>, then the behaviour is undefined"*.

Comment: Simply saying, what happens is that `printf` expects to get a 64-bit wide unsigned integer (`unsigned long long` is *usually* 64 bits wide), but you give it a 32-bit wide integer. Because of that it (probably) reads not only your parameter, but also some nearby bytes.

Comment: @KaranSingh: The variadic C functions like `printf` rely on the format string to know the size of the argument to pull from the `va_list`. If you give `printf` a format string that requires 8 bytes, but only provide 4 bytes on the argument list, things go very badly.

Comment: Wow, I get it now. It would be great if you added that to your answer. Also, I tried doing it with CHAR_MAX  and now I get 127 :)
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

As `printf` is expecting now to print a 64 bit value, you should pass it accordingly. You can cast it to `unsigned long long`:

```
    printf("%llu", (unsigned long long)ULONG_MAX);
```

Assuming a little endian architecture, you got that bigger value previously because only the least significant 32-bit word was passed as a parameter, and printf needed 64 bit, so it was using as the most significant 32-bit word whatever the stack contained at the next address.

The wrong value you got is 38654705663. If you display it in hexadecimal (you can also use `printf` for this with `%llx`), you get:
`0000 0008 FFFF FFFF` (spaces added by me for easier reading).

Comment: Thanks for explaining _why_ they were seeing different values between using `lu` and `llu`. So the upper 32-bit word of `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000` was just whatever garbage was laying around?

Comment: Yes, I just added in the answer the hex representation of the wrong value.

Answer (score 2):

With `%llu` you have to pass a long long integer to the `printf()`. Try this:

```
printf("%llu", (unsigned long long)ULONG_MAX);
```